# Many small files Vs 1 big file for AWS S3 and Glacier :

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-glacier

I have a streaming server as EC2 instance and the Video chunks duration is 8 seconds. I want to archive the stream for auditing purpose so I record the stream back as one file each 1 minute

should I save the 8 seconds chunks to S3 then to Glacier or save the combined 1-minute file

Which choice is better in terms of Cost and performance? for s3 and then for Glacier

Comment: How frequently you are going to need the archived video?

Comment: S3 and Glacier solve different problems.  There is no real comparison between the two. In terms of pricing glacier is much cheaper but it is not meant for frequent access. Glacier retrieval takes hours and is not comparable with retrieval of data from s3

Comment: @Shibashis I want to compare between "small files" and "big file"
please read the title

Comment: @error2007s : rarely , Just in case of the error

Comment: So the video will run from EC2 and when done you want to archive it right?

Comment: Amazon glacier adds storage metadata for each object. Reducing the number of objects stored in galacier will help you reduce the overhead cost. This is also recommended by Amazon glacier service. Here is the aws documentation for the same http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-archival.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to answer your question:

**You should upload the bigger file, which is the combined 1 minute file.**

In terms of cost, both S3 and Glacier charge you per request besides per GB storage you use, so uploading bigger chunks means less requests made to S3 and Glacier, thus saving costs.

In terms of performance, you said in the comments that you rarely need to retrieve the files, so I recommend you use Glacier. Beware though, that once you put a file inside Glacier, it will take a couple of hours to retrieve it back, so it is only suitable if you very rarely need the data, if not ever.

If you need to retrieve the data often, you should use S3 (data retrieval is instant). But S3 charges more for storage than Glacier, so there are pros and cons between both.